# clicking vote to undelete on an undeleted post shows undelete prompt again

Tags: discussion, bug

I clicked undelete on [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30098842/17447) and clicked OK

Then I clicked undeleted again out of curiousity as it is active. Then I got this message again.

[image: Undelete prompt]
Then when I clicked OK. I got a message like,

> You have already voted to undelete this post

My doubt is, is there a need for the `data-delete-prompt` when clicking undelete again?

P.S: The answer was undeleted as I was experimenting on it. I think the OP, seeing the undelete vote, undeleted it. Mods could you check how it got undeleted?

Also, I played with the answer below, which actually shouldn't be undeleted, just to test it. I would like to revert my vote, if I may.

**Update**: I [voted to undelete this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30047775/17447) and moved on to delete another. I still have 18 votes remaining. I mean votes are not descreasing in number. Am I missing something here?